# Infinite jump issue

Tags: c++, sfml, jumping

I am currently making a game in c++ using sfml, I encountered a problem where if I jump in my game, the jump mechanic allows the player to jump repeatedly in mid-air which is something I do not want. [Here is a video showing my issue.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7gEDwsnZGnA) I believe there is either an issue with my bool or collision but I am not sure what it is. Here is my player.h player.cpp and game.cpp.

player.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Precomp.h"

enum PLAYER_ANIMATION_STATES { Idle = 0, Left_Move, Right_Move, Jumping };

class Player
{

private:
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sf::Texture textureSheet;
    sf::Clock animationTimer;
    
    //Animation
    short animationStates;
    sf::IntRect currentFrame;
    bool animationSwitch;


    //Physics 
    sf::Vector2f velocity;
    sf::Vector2f position = sprite.getPosition();
    float x;
    float y;
    float maxVelocity;
    float minVelocity;
    float acceleration;
    float drag;
    float gravity;
    float MaxYVelocity;
    float time;
    float jumpVelocity;
    float maxJumpHeight;
    bool isJumping = false;
    bool canJump = true;
    
    
    
    

    //Health Points
    
    //Private functions
    void initVariables();
    void initTexture();
    void initSprite();
    void initAnimations();
    void initPhysics();

public:
    Player();
    virtual ~Player();

    //Accessors 
    const bool& getAnimationSwitch();
    const sf::Vector2f getPosition();
    const sf::FloatRect getGlobalBounds() const;
    const sf::Sprite& getSprite() const;

    //Modifiers
    void setPosition(const float x, const float y);
    void resetVeloictyY();
    void resetVelocityX();

    //Functions
    void resetAnimationTimer();
    void move(const float dir_x, const float dir_y);
    void setPlayerHitbox();
    void updatePhysics();
    void update();
    void updateAnimations();
    void updateMovement();
    void render(sf::RenderTarget& target);
    
};
```

player.cpp

```
include "Player.h"

void Player::initVariables()
{
    this->animationStates = PLAYER_ANIMATION_STATES::Idle;
}


void Player::initTexture()
{
        //lLoad a texture
        if (!this->textureSheet.loadFromFile("Sprites and Textures/Kim Pine Full Sprite Sheet 3.png"))
        {
            std::cout << "Failed";
        }
}

void Player::initSprite()
{
    //Set the texture to the sprite

    this->sprite.setTexture(this->textureSheet);

    //Resize the sprite
    this->sprite.scale(3.f, 3.f);
    this->currentFrame = sf::IntRect(0, 0 , 48, 95);
    this->sprite.setTextureRect(this->currentFrame);
}

void Player::initAnimations()
{
    this->animationTimer.restart();
    this->animationSwitch = true;

}

void Player::initPhysics()
{
    this->maxVelocity = 10.f;
    this->minVelocity = 1.f;
    this->acceleration = 1.05f;
    this->drag = 0.96f;
    this->gravity = 4.f;
    this->MaxYVelocity = -15.f;
    this->time = 1.f;
    this->jumpVelocity = -12.0f;

}

Player::Player()
{
    this->initVariables();
    this->initTexture();
    this->initSprite();
    this->initAnimations();
    this->initPhysics();

    

}

Player ::~Player()
{

}

const bool& Player::getAnimationSwitch()
{
    bool anim_switch = this->animationSwitch;

    if (this->animationSwitch)
        this->animationSwitch = false;

    return anim_switch; //Have not documented this yet as I have not fixed the animation yet
}

const sf::Vector2f Player::getPosition()
{
    return this->sprite.getPosition();
}

const sf::FloatRect Player::getGlobalBounds() const
{
    return this->sprite.getGlobalBounds();
}

const sf::Sprite& Player::getSprite() const
{
    return this->sprite;
}

void Player::setPosition(const float x, const float y)
{
    this->sprite.setPosition(x, y);
}

void Player::resetVeloictyY()
{
    this->velocity.y = 0.f;
}

void Player::resetVelocityX()
{
    this->velocity.x = 0.f;
}


void Player::updateAnimations()
{
    if (this->animationStates == PLAYER_ANIMATION_STATES::Idle)
    {
        if (this->animationTimer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() >= 0.25f || this->getAnimationSwitch())
        {
            this->currentFrame.top = 0.f;
            this->currentFrame.left += 49.25f;
            if (this->currentFrame.left >= 147.75f)
                this->currentFrame.left = 0;


            this->animationTimer.restart();
            this->sprite.setTextureRect(this->currentFrame);
        }
    }
    else if (this->animationStates == PLAYER_ANIMATION_STATES::Right_Move)
    {

        if (this->animationTimer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() >= 0.1f || this->getAnimationSwitch())
        {
            this->currentFrame.top = 92.0f;
            this->currentFrame.left += 49.1f;
            if (this->currentFrame.left >= 245.9f)
                this->currentFrame.left = 0;


            this->animationTimer.restart();
            this->sprite.setTextureRect(this->currentFrame);
            
        }
        this->sprite.setScale(3.f, 3.f);
        this->sprite.setOrigin(0.f, 0.f);
    }
    else if (this->animationStates == PLAYER_ANIMATION_STATES::Left_Move)
    {

        if (this->animationTimer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() >= 0.1f || this->getAnimationSwitch())
        {
            this->currentFrame.top = 92.0f;
            this->currentFrame.left += 49.1f;
            if (this->currentFrame.left >= 245.9f)
                this->currentFrame.left = 0;


            this->animationTimer.restart();
            this->sprite.setTextureRect(this->currentFrame);
            
        }
        this->sprite.setScale(-3.f, 3.f);
        this->sprite.setOrigin(this->sprite.getGlobalBounds().width / 3.f, 0.f);
    }
    /*
    else if (this->animationStates == PLAYER_ANIMATION_STATES::Jumping)
    {
        if (this->animationTimer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() >= 0.1f || this->getAnimationSwitch())
        {
            this->currentFrame.top = 196.0f;
            this->currentFrame.left += 59.8f;
            if (this->currentFrame.left >= 778.f)
                this->currentFrame.left = 0;


            this->animationTimer.restart();
            this->sprite.setTextureRect(this->currentFrame);

        }
        this->sprite.setScale(3.f, 3.f);
        this->sprite.setOrigin(0.f, 0.f);
    }
    */
    else
    {
        this->animationTimer.restart();
    }
}

void Player::updateMovement()
{
        //Move Player
        this->animationStates = PLAYER_ANIMATION_STATES::Idle;

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::A) || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Left))
    {
        this->move(-1.f, 0.f);
        this->animationStates = PLAYER_ANIMATION_STATES::Left_Move;

    }
    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::D) || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Right))
    {
        this->move(1.f, 0.f);
        this->animationStates = PLAYER_ANIMATION_STATES::Right_Move;

    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W) || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space) || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up) && canJump)
    {
            this->velocity.y = jumpVelocity;
            this->canJump = false;
            this->animationStates = PLAYER_ANIMATION_STATES::Jumping;
            
            if (sf::Event::KeyReleased)
            {
                if (this->velocity.y < -12.f)
                    this->velocity.y = -12.f;
            }

    }
        /*
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S) || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
        {
            this->sprite.move(0.f, 1.f);

        }
    */
}

void Player::resetAnimationTimer()
{
    this->animationTimer.restart();
    this->animationSwitch = true;
}

void Player::move(const float dir_x, const float dir_y)
{
    //Accceleration
    this->velocity.x += dir_x * this->acceleration;
    

    //Limit Velocity
    if (std::abs(this->velocity.x) > this->maxVelocity)
    {
        this->velocity.x = this->maxVelocity * ((this->velocity.x < 0.f) ? -1.f : 1.f);
    }

}   

void Player::updatePhysics()
{
    /*
    //Gravity
    this->velocity.y += 1.0 * this->gravity;
    if (std::abs(this->velocity.y) > this->MaxYVelocity)
    {
        this->velocity.y = this->MaxYVelocity * ((this->velocity.y < 0.f) ? -1.f : 1.f);
    }
    */

    //Deceleration
    this->velocity *= this->drag;

    //Limit Deceleration
    if (std::abs(this->velocity.x) < this->minVelocity)
        this->velocity.x = 0.f;
    if (std::abs(this->velocity.y) < this->minVelocity)
        this->velocity.y = 0.f;

    this->sprite.move(this->velocity);
    this->velocity.y += gravity * time;

    //Jump Gravity
    
    /*
    if (canJump)
    {
        this->velocity.y = 0.f;
        this->canJump = true;
    }
    */

    
    if (this->sprite.getPosition().y + this->sprite.getGlobalBounds().height >= 600)
    {
        this->canJump = false;
        this->velocity.y = 0.f;
        this->sprite.setPosition(this->sprite.getPosition().x, 600 - this->sprite.getGlobalBounds().height);

    }
    

}

void Player::update()
{
    this->updateMovement();
    this->updatePhysics();
    this->updateAnimations();
    
}

void Player::setPlayerHitbox()
{
    
}

void Player::render(sf::RenderTarget& target)
{
    target.draw(this->sprite);

    sf::CircleShape circ;
    circ.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    circ.setRadius(2.f);
    circ.setPosition(this->sprite.getPosition());

    target.draw(circ);

};
```

game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"


//Private Functions


void Game::initPlayer()
{
    this->player = new Player();
}

void Game::initPlatform()
{
    sf::RectangleShape platform(sf::Vector2f(200.f, 20.f));
    platform.setPosition(300.f, 500.f);
    platform.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
}

void Game::initVariables()
{
    
}

void Game::initWindow()
{
    this->window.create(sf::VideoMode(800,600), "CFFA Window", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);
    this->window.setFramerateLimit(144);

}

//Constructors 

Game :: Game()
{
    this->initVariables();
    this->initWindow();
    this->initPlayer();

}

Game ::~Game()
{
    
    delete this->player;
}

const bool Game::running() const
{
    return this->window.isOpen();
}

//Accessors

//Functions

void Game::render()
{
    /*
        return void

        - clears the old frame
        - renders the new objects
        - displays the frame in the new window

        Renders the game objects
    */

    this->window.clear();

    //Draw game objects
    this->renderPlayer();

    this->window.display();
}

void Game::update()
{
    //Event Polling
    while (this->window.pollEvent(this->ev))
    {
        if (this->ev.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        {
            this->window.close();
        }
        else if (this->ev.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && this->ev.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
        { 
            this->window.close();
        }
        if (this->ev.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased &&
            (this->ev.key.code == sf::Keyboard::D ||
                this->ev.key.code == sf::Keyboard::A ||
                this->ev.key.code == sf::Keyboard::W ||
                this->ev.key.code == sf::Keyboard::S
                )
            ) // Need to Document when animation fixed

            this->player->resetAnimationTimer();
    }
    
    this->updatePlayer();
}

void Game::renderPlayer()
{
    this->player->render(this->window);
}

const sf::RenderWindow & Game::getWindow() const
{
    // TODO: insert return statement here
    return this->window;
}

void Game::updatePlayer()
{
    this->player->update();
    this->updateCollision();
}

void Game::updateCollision()
{
    //Collision with Window
    if (this->player->getPosition().y + this->player->getGlobalBounds().height > this->window.getSize().y)
    {
        this->player->resetVeloictyY();
        this->player->setPosition(this->player->getPosition().x, this->window.getSize().y - this->player->getGlobalBounds().height);
    }
    if (this->player->getPosition().x + this->player->getGlobalBounds().width > this->window.getSize().x)
    {
        this->player->resetVelocityX();
        this->player->setPosition(this->window.getSize().x - this->player->getGlobalBounds().width, this->player->getPosition().y);
    }
    if (this->player->getPosition().x < 0)
    {
        this->player->resetVelocityX();
        this->player->setPosition(0, this->player->getPosition().y);
    }
    //Check collision between objects
    
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You have linked a private video, so we cannot watch it. What does it mean to be a "pseudo-fly mechanic"? Are you able to repeatedly jump in mid air, like Flappy Bird? Or do you mean gravity fails to pull the character's trajectory back down into a fall after the peak of the jump? Or something else?

Comment: @DMGregory Sorry, I've now made the video viewable. To be clearer, it is a multiple jump issue where the player can jump repeatedly in mid air as well as this, holding down the jump button allows the player to jump infinitely. I'll change my wording to make it clearer now.

Comment: I am willing to bet that the infinite jumps do not occur when you press the up arrow.
... That they only occur for space or w.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is pretty easy to spot. It is located at this line of code.

```
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W) || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space) || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up) && canJump)
```

So what is the problem.

If we seperate this `if` statement into the seperate parts we have:

`if (isKeyPressed('w')`

`if (isKeyPressed('Space')`

`if (isKeyPressed('Up') && canJump`

Do you see the problem?

I recommend changing this code in 2 ways.

1. Wrap things in parenthesis properly, also simplify your `if` statements.
2. Check canJump first to shortcut all of the other checks. (No need to check if a key is pressed if the character cannot jump).

```
// This will be inlined and have no performance hit whatseover...
// and is less prone to errors/ allows you to easily change your implementation
// to allow for player key mapping...
inline bool jumpKeyPressed() {
   return sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W) || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space) || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)
}
... 

if (canJump && jumpKeyPressed()) {
    enter code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the fact I messed up on something very simple is an indicator of my inexperience. Thanks to your advice I was able to correct my code and also clean it up.  I will use this as an indicator in future functions I attempt to implement!